# Grails TransientObjectException using bindData

Tags: exception, grails, data-binding

has a behavior I can not understand.

I have 2 domain class, i'm using this names to illustrate the problem, Foo and Bar that is:

```
[Foo]
class Foo {
 String value1
}

[Bar]
class Bar {
  String value1

  static belongsTo = [foo: Foo] 
}
```

Now im my controller i have this:

```
def createBar = {
   def foo = foo.get(params['foo_id'].toLong()) //this is a hidden field in form
   def bar = new Bar()
   bindData(bar, params, [exclude:['foo']])
   bindData(bar, foo, [include:['foo']] //This not work!

   //bar.foo = foo //This works fine! 
   bar.save()
}
```

When i save using just bindData the controller throws TransientObjectException saying the Foo is unsaved, but when i use the second form, the actions works fine, and saves the domain without exceptions.

Why this happens? I not understand, because for me, the bindValue() and the bar.foo  is the same behavior.

I'm not using dbCreate in my app, only validate, this is the representations of the tables:

```
[Foo]
id (PK)
value1 (varchar)

[Bar]
id (PK)
value2 (varchar)
foo_id (FK)
```

I'm using grails 2.2.3

Thanks.

Comment: It looks like `foo.get` should throw a NullPointerException, where is `foo` defined?

Comment: In my form i have a hidden fiel, and it contains de foo id. A AJAX request is generated and the action is called. But the get returns a valid object from DB.

Answer (score 0):

There are all sorts of problems with your code.

You're passing the instance of foo to the excludes, also the method name is `bindData` not `bindValue`:

```
bindValue(bar, params, [exclude:[foo]])
```

This should be

```
bindData(bar, params, [exclude:['foo']])
```

Comment: Sorry Graeme, I made a mistake in typing. I'm editing the question. Thank you.